# MBTilesRasterDataSource not found from nutiteq SDK?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, gps, offline

Recently i just followed the examples of [**Nutiteq SDK** from here.](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/tree/master/HelloMap3D/src/com/nutiteq/hellomap)

But unfortunately the **MBTilesRasterDataSource** is not found. Eclipse shows error on the variable statement on that line. I check inside the package **com.nutiteq.rasterdatasources.** but found no class using that name. Where does it come from anyway?

Answer (score 2):

- The class `MBTilesRasterDataSource` is part of their [advancedlayers library](http://nutiteq.github.io/advancedlayers/)
- Looks like in the new version of this library, the class `MBTilesRasterDataSource` is available under `com.nutiteq.datasources.raster`

  - change your import package declaration to `com.nutiteq.datasources.raster`, the eclipse error should go away.

[image: MBTilesRasterDataSource]